# Xamarin.Forms Java.Lang.NullPointerException when ContentPage has SizeChanged event listener

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following error message when I try to overwrite a Xamarin.Forms `ContentPage.Content`.

I just get the message if the new `ContentPage` has a `SizeChanged` event listener.

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException
  Message=Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
```

**Code of the ContentPage I want to load**

```
    public class ShowSizePage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly Label label;
        public ShowSizePage()
        {
            label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = "initialized",
            };

            SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;
            Content = label;
        }
        void OnPageSizeChanged (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            label.Text = String.Format("{0} \u00D7 {1}", Width, Height);
        }

    }
```

**Code from the caller of above ContentPage**

```
// Part of an other ContentPage
        void OnShowSizeClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ContentPage c = new ShowSizePage();

            Content = c.Content; // Exception is caused here
        }
```

I don't get the Exception if I call `ShowSizePage` directly from my `MainPage`.

What do I have to change to avoid the Exception?

**Edit minimal reproducible example code:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NP_Exception
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Change this to false to see that ShowSizePage works properly if not loaded through MenuPage
            bool showMenu = true;

            if (showMenu)
                MainPage = new MenuPage(); // Throws exception
            else
                MainPage = new ShowSizePage(); // Works
        }
    }

    public class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly StackLayout menu = new StackLayout();
        readonly ScrollView menuView = new ScrollView();
        public MenuPage ()
        {
            Button showSizeButton = new Button { Text = "Show Size" };
            showSizeButton.Clicked += OnShowSizeClicked;
            menu.Children.Add(showSizeButton);

            Button showLabelButton = new Button { Text = "Show Label" };
            showLabelButton.Clicked += OnShowLabelClicked;
            menu.Children.Add(showLabelButton);

            menuView.Content = menu;

            Content = menuView;
        }    
        void OnShowSizeClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ContentPage c = new ShowSizePage();

            Content = c.Content; // Exception is caused here
        }

        void OnShowLabelClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ContentPage c = new ShowLabelPage();

            Content = c.Content;
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            Content = menuView;

            return true;
        }
    }
    public class ShowSizePage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly Label label;
        public ShowSizePage()
        {
            label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = "initialized",
            };

            SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;
            Content = label;
        }
        void OnPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            label.Text = String.Format("{0} \u00D7 {1}", Width, Height);
        }

    }
    public class ShowLabelPage : ContentPage {
        public ShowLabelPage ()
        {
            Content = new Label { Text = "Hello World! Press hardware back button for menu." };
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The exception occurs on Xamarin.Forms v4.4.0.991265 but seems to be fixed in v4.6.0.726

Comment: Can you please provide us a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I use your code while I did not reproduce the problem. The OnPageSizeChanged  does not raise. I found an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8801) in Github which similar to you problem and you can have a look at.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I still can't see the exception on my side, I uploaded my test project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/SizeChanged--TestSample).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I cloned your solution and it shows the label 'Initialized' instead of the screen dimensions. If you set ```showMenu=false``` you will see that the ```SizeChanged``` event is called. Anyway, there seems to be a difference in our solutions even though the code is the same. I will have to run a git diff over both of our solutions to see what is different in yours. I will keep you updated. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Yes, I think you can check if the version of Xamarin.form we are using is the same.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Updated my post. I was using v4.4 while you were using v4.6

Comment: I added an answer and can you please mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of Xamrin.forms `v4.6.0.726`. Anyone who meet this issue with earlier version can update your `Xamarin.Forms` to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to get rid of the Exception while getting the desired result.

I had to wrap the Page Content into a `ContentView` and bind the `SizeChanged` event to the `ContentView`

**Working Code Sample**:

```
    public class ShowSizePage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly Label label;
        public ShowSizePage()
        {
            label = new Label
            {
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = "initialized",
            };

            // Wrap Content in ContentView to avoid Exception
            ContentView view = new ContentView { Content = label };

            // Bind SizeChanged event to view
            view.SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;

            // Set View as Content
            Content = view;
        }
        void OnPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            // Use Width & Height of the sender object
            View view = (View)sender;

            label.Text = String.Format("{0} \u00D7 {1}", view.Width, view.Height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice! One question, if you only want the Content from the Page why don't you use a ContentView directly? You can use a `ContentView` as the `Content` for your other Pages.

Comment: @pinedax I think I tried using a ```ContentView``` on the calling element but it either crashed or it did not calculate the ```SizeChanged``` dimensions correctly. In my real solution, I'm including the pages via Reflection so I wanted to keep everything as open as possible. I'm just starting with C# so I'm thankful for every advice that I can get.